# Cannot acces object from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

In my ASP.NET MVC application, in ..\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml I have the following line of code:

```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mycontrols.com/Scripts/MyConstants.js"></script>
```

File MyConstants.js contains below:

```
var MyConstants = function() {
   return {
       DataObject1: {
          MyEnum1: {
             Item0: 0,
             Item1: 1,
             Item3: 2
          }
       },
       DataObject2: {
          MyEnum2: {
             Item0: 0,
             Item1: 1,
             Item3: 2
          }
       }
   };
};
```

Now from my view (Index.cshtml) I am trying to access in javascript to an item from MyEnum1:

```
var myEnum = MyConstants.DataObject1.MyEnum1.Item1;
```

but it does not work, below the error en devtools in chrome:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'MyEnum1'of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyEnum1' of undefined

Comment: `jQuery.Deferred exception` would occur when your code is inside a jquery callback (eg doc.ready) when the property doesn't exist.  If you're using `()` (or not) correctly according to Rory's answer then it's possible your code is running before your `var` has been setup correct (eg your `<script src=myconstants.js` is not working.  Add an `alert` as the first line in the include script to ensure it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyConstants` is a function which returns an object, so you need to invoke it:

```
var myEnum = MyConstants().DataObject1.MyEnum1.Item1;
```

If you'd prefer to keep your current syntax to retrieve the value, then you need to convert `MyConstants` to an object:

```js
var MyConstants = {
  DataObject1: {
    MyEnum1: {
      Item0: 0,
      Item1: 1,
      Item3: 2
    }
  },
  DataObject2: {
    MyEnum2: {
      Item0: 0,
      Item1: 1,
      Item3: 2
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I have changed to MyConstants() instead of using MyConstants but it does not work.From devtools in chrome I have checked this line and chrome gets MyConstants.DataObject1.MyEnum1.Item1 even if I type in javascript MyConstants().DataObject1.MyEnum1.Item1

Comment: In which case we need more information about the error, and how and when you include the script in the page, as the example above works fine.

Comment: Finally I have solved, change was not being applied correctly. After clearing chrome cache and history it works. Thx.